# Bitwise operator to convert 0 to 1 and 1 to 0

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

In C, suppose I have an unsigned char A which can be either 0 or 1.
I would like to find a bitwise logical operator that will convert
A to !A.

Note: I am using this code on a GPU, where bitwise operators are very cheap compared to logical operators. i.e. XOR is much cheaper than !

Comment: what do you mean with "!A"? That doesnt make any sense, there is no inversion of a character.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If by 'not' you mean send 1 to 0 and 0 to 1. you can use the XOR operator `^` to do that. If character is called c, you can write `c = c ^ 1;`.

Comment: Also, if I treat a true boolean expression as a char, is that char equal to 1 ? i.e.  char test = (A == 1);       Is test equal to 1 in this case?

Comment: @Jacko Yes it is. Also, you should use `A = !A;` from another answer. `c = c ^ 1` will only invert the first bit of the char and I have ho idea why would you need to do it.

Comment: Thanks, HolyBlackCat.  But, if c == 0, then c^1 will equal 1. And if c ==1, then c^1 will equal 0. So this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Thank you , saadtaame.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the "logical not" operator:

`A = !A;`

You can also use the "bitwise not" operator, but this will make your code harder to understand since what you are doing is actually a logical not:

`A = ~A;`

Comment: I've neutralised the downvote; I thought your answer was intuitive!

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to avoid logical operators. I have added this to the question.

Comment: I don't know about other languages but in C#, you get negative numbers if you use "~" and error if you use "!".

Answer (score 1):

XOR assignment with `1` is handy if you just need a flag to toggle repeatedly.

```
$ clang -x c -include stdio.h -pipe -o meh - <<\EOF && ./meh
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned char x = '\0';
    for (int n = 0; n <= 50; n++) printf("%d", x ^= 1);
    return 0;
}
EOF

101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101
```